# remove the line from the file and add the another entry in same position using sed

Tags: shell, sed

One of the parameter into the property file is `JAVA_HOME=/var/tmp/java/jdk1.x.x`
planning to remove entire line of JAVA_HOME and add the new `JAVA_HOME=/var/tmp/java/jdk11.0.5` into the same like of the property file using SED command.

ex:Remove the line 3 and add the `JAVA_HOME=/var/tmp/java/jdk11.0.5` into the same location line 3.

```
#!/bin/sh
export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/ibm/oracle
export JAVA_HOME=/var/tmp/java/java1.8.0.31
```

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: It sounds like you are just replacing `jdk1.x.x` with `jdk11.0.5`.  There's no need to think of it as removing a line and adding a new line in the same place.  That's a bit convoluted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backup the original file and try this `sed` command:

```
sed -i 's%JAVA_HOME=.*%JAVA_HOME=/var/tmp/java/jdk11.0.5%' file
```